# Visual Studio 2017 me elimina lineas del Designer.cs de un form c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un proyecto con varios windows forms hechos con Visual Studio Community 2017.
Cuando trabajo directamente sobre el Form.Designer.cs me borra lineas solo, creo que al guardar proyecto. Estas lineas las escribo manualmente por código, sin embargo, las que hago a través de los "Eventos" del Form se guardan bien.
Un ejemplo del código que se borra, en el Form.Designer.cs tengo:

```
// 
// textbox1
// 
//this.textbox1.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(Clase_Funciones.textboxes_Validating);
```

Como ven, desde el Designer llamo a una funcion de validaciones que tengo en una clase.
Alguien sabe como solucionarlo o que estoy haciendo mal ?
Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Los ficheros `.Designer.cs` son autogenerados y no están pensados para ser modificados manualmente, es normal que pierdas los cambios que introduces a mano. Para introducir cambios en el código del form puedes usar [clases y métodos parciales](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods).

Comment: Entonces desde el Handler del .Designer.cs "apunto" al Evento del Form, y del Evento del Form a la funcion que está en la clase ? Así tengo código innecesario en el Form, ¿no es mejor directamente desde el Handler llamar a la función de la clase ?